# Some way to surround string with other text in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, string, text

I have the following PHP function:

```
    public function createOptions($options, $cfg=array()) {
        $cfg['methodKey'] = isset($cfg['methodKey']) ? $cfg['methodKey'] : 'getId';
        $cfg['methodValue'] = isset($cfg['methodValue']) ? $cfg['methodValue'] : 'getName';
        $cfg['beforeKey'] = isset($cfg['beforeKey']) ? $cfg['beforeKey'] : '';
        $cfg['beforeValue'] = isset($cfg['beforeValue']) ? $cfg['beforeValue'] : '';
        $cfg['afterKey'] = isset($cfg['afterKey']) ? $cfg['afterKey'] : '';
        $cfg['afterValue'] = isset($cfg['afterValue']) ? $cfg['afterValue'] : '';
        $array = array();
        foreach ($options as $obj) {
            $array[$cfg['beforeKey'] . $obj->$cfg['methodKey']() . $cfg['afterKey']] = $cfg['beforeValue'] . $obj->$cfg['methodValue']() . $cfg['afterValue'];
        }
        return $array;
}
```

It's something I use around my app to create select boxes from array data. I just recently added 4 new $cfg variables for adding strings before or after the key and value of the select box. So for example, if my drop down list looked like "A, B, C" by default, I can pass:

```
$cfg['beforeValue'] = 'Select ';
$cfg['afterValue'] = ' now!';
```

and get "Select A now!, Select B now!, Select C now!"

So this works fine, but I was wondering if there was some way in PHP to accomplish this in one line sorta speak rather than two. I figure there must be a special way to do this.

Comment: Like with [`sprintf()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) ? `sprintf("Select %s now!", $cfg['methodValue'])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, simplify that horrendous code with this:

```
public function createOptions($options, array $cfg = array()) {
    $cfg += array(
        'methodKey'   => 'getId',
        'methodValue' => 'getName',
        ...
    );
```

No need for all the `isset` and repeated key names, a simple array union will do.

Secondly, you can use something like [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
$cfg['surroundingValue'] = 'Select %s now!';
echo sprintf($cfg['surroundingValue'], $valueInTheMiddle);
```

Comment: I have used array merging before, but it never even occurred to me to use it in a spot like this. So thanks for that.

Correct me if I'm wrong but $cfg += array(//defaultconditions) is the same as $cfg = $cfg + array(//defaultconditions) which is the same as array_merge($cfg, array(//defaultconditions).

Basically if the key exists in $cfg, that will be the value used in the resulting $cfg variable, otherwise, the default value will be used.

Comment: @Justin In this case, yes, it's all the same. `array_merge` and `+` only differ in their handling of numeric indexes.